# JBoss EAP5, can the /work directory be cleared?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I am constantly clearing the /tmp/ and /data/ directories. Is it ok to delete the /work directory? Does it only contain runtime cache data?

Answer (score 5):

**The work Directory**

- Directory where compiled JSP `.java` and `.class` files reside
- Also contains cached TLDs
- Very useful for debugging problems in JSPs

Java ServerPages (`.jsp` files) are automatically compiled into Java Servlets (`.java` file) and then into Java byte-code (`.class` files) by Tomcat (the embedded servlet engine running within JBoss AS).

Many JSP errors are easier to fix when developers are able to look at the compiled .java files and match the line numbers to error/exception messages.

Unless you care to preserve compiled JSPs, **this directory can be cleared (deleted) between JBoss restarts**.

An easy solution is to configure JBoss Web deployer to destroy the contents of the work directory at shutdown through configuration.

Change in `server\<instance_name>\deployers\jbossweb.deployer\META-INF\war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml`

```
<!--Flag to delete the Work Dir on Context Destroy -->
<property name="deleteWorkDirOnContextDestroy">false</property>
```

to

```
<!--Flag to delete the Work Dir on Context Destroy -->
<property name="deleteWorkDirOnContextDestroy">true</property>
```